# OpenVPN - Adding Send & Receive buffer for higher data/bandwidth throughput

Tags: linux, openvpn

Good day all

While setting up a OpenVPN server on a 1Gbps Fibre line, I had issues with bandwidth throughput, there was no other traffic.

To be clear, I had a 500Mbps Fibre line where I was and the server had a 1Gbps Fibre line.

After some searching around, I came accross [this](http://djlab.com/2015/02/openvpn-slow-downloads-on-windows-clients/)

I added these options

> sndbuf 393216
>
> rcvbuf 393216
>
> push "sndbuf 393216"
>
> push "rcvbuf 393216"

However it did not improve my connection drastically.

**Before:**

> 10Mbps Down 6-8Mbps Up

**After :**

> 12-14Mbps Down 7-10Mbps Up

**Should this value increase or decrease, how does this affect the data sent/recieved?**

server config as follows:

```
port 1025
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.252
push "redirect-gateway def1"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo no

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 4

#possible bandwidth increase
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
push "remote-gateway x.x.x.x"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
ccd-exclusive

#for checking active clients
management localhost 7505
```

*It was [suggested](http://winaero.com/blog/speed-up-openvpn-and-get-faster-speed-over-its-channel/) that I experiment with fragments, mss-fix, mtu and so forth which all proved fruitless, my current setup had the best performance. Any other change resulted in either slower performance or delays/ping spikes.*

Comment: Have you tested bandwidth between servers outside of OpenVPN? How certain are you that OpenVPN is the problem here? What other statistics have you gathered?

Comment: the 500Mbps is my university conenction, I average sftp speeds of +/- 450Mbps from my server with the 1Gbps line. For other stats: Each time I changed a setting i.e. buffer size, mtu, mss, fragment setting, I restarted my OpenVPN daemon and did a speedtest while connected to OpenVPN

Comment: Encryption might be a problem. You might consider using the weakest possible (blowfish-cbc?). Another problem may be the way you're doing your speed test. The correct methodology would be first measuring `pv </dev/zero >/dev/null` then measuring `pv </dev/zero | nc server:port` (with `nc -l host:port >/dev/null` on the other end) then measuring that same `nc` pipeline over the OpenVPN link.

Comment: You might also have a userspace buffering problem. Consider looking at `mbuffer`.

Comment: How do you test tunnel performance?

Answer (score -3):

There's OS network stack buffers, and there's OpenVPN network buffers. OpenVPN is all the way intending to reinvent the wheel, so the situation with buffers isn't surprising. First of all, you should ensure you are having enogh buffers in OS, I'd recommend setting `sndbuf`/`rvcbuf` to 0, tweak OS buffers and watch the effects - this way you won't get the chicken/egg dilemma.

Second... One Gbps and OpenVPN... really ? I'd recommend laying down some napalm on your OpenVPN installation, waiting a bit for it to absorb and just burning it all down. There's clearly something wrong with an installation that requires speed this high and OpenVPN - something designed so lateral and compatible with itself only... (yeah, yeah I know, plenty of qualified "home" engineers use OpenVPN and "everything is okay", but this thing is called *scalability* - it's when you can use the same technology to handle 1 units or 1000 units of same type - and OpenVPN just isn't one of these *scalable*  solutions) After all, may be it's encryption, that really kills your bandwidth ? You didn't show any CPU stats while getting to the top of the speed, and, considering OpenVPN designers and programmers complicated relationships with reality, I wouldn't be that suprised seeing OpenVPN eating all the CPU.

Final advice (one that you probably won't follow, but still; plus - I just like the irony of wasting good advice) you should take a good look on your installation and find some good reason to have 1 Gpbs encrypted between two points, instead of just using some secure transport like dedicated link of vlan; and if you really do, you should consider moving to some standard solution, like IPsec between dedicated devices - ones that either have onboard accelerator (like Cisco and Juniper), or, at least can benefit from AES-NI while running it in software. But 1 Gbps link, from my point of view, must be handled by some decent dedicated equipment. *Hint*: if you don't have a funding needed, you probably don't need encryption at all.